# For loop with dynamic list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the for-loop:

```
L=[1,2,3,4]
```

I want, that the code below works:

```
for i in range(1,len(L)):
   if i%2==0:
      L.remove(L[i])
```

How can I do this?
Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "I want, that the code below works"?

Answer (score 0):

So you want even indexed elements? Comprehensions are your friend.

`L = [e for i,e in enumerate(L) if i % 2]`

Comment: What about `L[::2]`?

Comment: @mgilson that's something I've never seen before - really neat. Is there a name for that style?

Comment: I hope veingrow will google what enumerate does and what is list comprehension.

Comment: @TylerSebastian It's called the `step` or the `stride`, an optional argument for list slicing.

Comment: @TylerSebastian Its just a part of list slicing. The third term (if any) defines the step size

Comment: @Matt neat, thanks.